# Python3 multiprocessing: Memory Allocation Error

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times, but the answers are not applicable.
This is [answer one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787678/writing-a-parallel-loop) of a parallelized loop using multiprocessing on StackoverFlow:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def processInput(i):
    return i * i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = range(1000000)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    results = pool.map(processInput, inputs)
    print(results)
```

This code works fine. But if I increase the range to 1000000000, my 16GB of Ram are getting filled completely and I get *[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory*. It seems as if the *map* function starts as many processes as possible. How do I limit the number of parallel processes?

Answer (score 1):

The pool.map function starts 4 processes as you instructed it (in the line processes=4 you instruct the pool on how many processes it can use to perform your logic).

There is however a different issue underlying this implementation.
The pool.map function will return a list of objects, in this case its numbers.
Numbers do not act like int-s in ANSI-C they have overhead and will not overflow (e.g. turn to -2^31 whenever reaching 2^31+1 on 32-bit).
Also python lists are not array and do incur an overhead.

To be more specific, on python 3.6, running the following code will reveal some overhead:

```
>>>import sys
>>>t = [1,2,3,4]
>>>sys.getsizeof(t)
96
>>>t = [x for x in range(1000)]
>>>sys.getsizeof(t)
9024
```

So this means 24 bytes per number on small lists and ~9 bytes on large lists.
So for a list the size of 10^9 we get about 8.5GB

EDIT: 1. As tfb mentioned, this is not even the size of the underlying Number objects, just pointers and list overhead, meaning there is much more memory overhead I did not account for in the original answer.

2. Default python installation on windows is 32-bit (you can get 64-bit installation but you need to check the section of all available downloads in the python website), So I assumed you are using the 32-bit installation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `sys.getsizeof` just tells you the size of the array object, not its contents.  For instance `1.0*sys.getsizeof([[i for i in xrange(10)] for j in xrange(10000)])/10000` is about 8.7 on my implementation.  So clearly it's not counting the objects in the array, just pointers to them.  And `sys.getsizeof(1)` is 24.  (Python doesn't seem to do anything clever with tagging so fixnums can be immediate as far as I can see.)

Answer (score 0):

`range(1000000000)` creates a list of 10^9 `int`s. This is around 8GB (8 bytes per `int` on a 64-bit system).  You are then trying to process this to create another list of 10^9 `int`s.  A really really smart implementation might be able to do this on a 16GB machine, but its basically a lost cause.

In Python 2 you could try using `xrange` which might or might not help.  I am not sure what the Python 3 equivalent is.

Comment: python 3 has deprecated the range implementation for the xrange generator, range() in python 3 is equal to using xrange() in python 2.

Comment: @Fanchi Thanks.  I'm probably going to delete this answer because I think yours is better.